# C#: DLL is registered but COM error 80040154 still appear

Tags: c#, dll, com, solidworks, clsid

When I *debug* my *Windows Form Application* I get this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {27526253-6119-4B38-A1F9-2DC877E72334} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

and because of it, my *WFA* can't interface with the software *Solidworks* installed on my computer; the only library that *WFA* needs to interface with *Solidworks* is
`SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll` (native position in the *Solidworks* directory **C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp 2017\SOLIDWORKS\SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll**).

Other informations below.

- Compiler: *Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express*
- Operating system: *Microsoft Windows 7* `64 bit` (updated)
- Logged account: *Administrator*
- Framework of destination of WFA: *Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Client
  Profile*
- Architecture of WFA: `x86` (32 bit)
- Architecture of the library: `x86` (32 bit)

When I added the library `SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll` into my project references, through *Visual Studio*, there wasn't the CLSID

> {27526253-6119-4B38-A1F9-2DC877E72334}

into the *Windows registry*, so I tried to register that library in these ways:

1. - Pasted `SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll` into directory
     **C:\Windows\SysWOW64**
   - Ran *Command Prompt* as *Administrator*, than typed **C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll**
   - Pressed *Enter*
   - Read this message:

> The module **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll** was
>   loaded but
>       the call to DllRegisterServer failed...

So, the library was not registered.

2. - Pasted `SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll` into the directory
     **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**
   - Ran *Command Prompt* as *Administrator*, than typed **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regasm
     SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll**
   - Pressed *Enter*
   - Read this message:

> The types were registered.

So, I think, now the library is registered, in fact I see the CLSID

> {27526253-6119-4B38-A1F9-2DC877E72334}

into the *Windows registry*.

The problem, however, persists.

3. In my `C#` code I created a `new Guid`; this is the code:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;

   namespace CreateModelSW
   {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       //Create interface
       SldWorks swApp;

       private void buttonCreateModel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           //Kill Solidworks processes
           Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("SLDWORKS");
           foreach (Process process in processes)
           {
               process.CloseMainWindow();
               process.Kill();
           }

           //Create new GUID
           Guid myGuid1 = new Guid("27526253-6119-4B38-A1F9-2DC877E72334");
           object processSW = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myGuid1));

           //Create new SOLIDWORKS Part
           swApp = (SldWorks)processSW;
           swApp.Visible = true;
           swApp.NewPart();
       }
   }
   }
   ```

The problem persists.

Can you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Do not use Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile, use Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 instead.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: registration is done on the native code not on managed interop dll. use oleview to see if the COM server is registered. if not, refer to official manual on which file you should be registering.

Comment: @Sheng Jiang 蒋晟: You are right: using OLEViewer I don't see this COM.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Can you please explain why I have to use Framework 4.0 instead of 4.0 Client Profile? Is this a general rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using version agnostic progId, try this :

```
SldWorks swApp = (SldWorks)Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application"));
```