# Retrieving COM class factory failed error: 80040154

Tags: c#, eclipse, solidworks

Thank you for reading.

I am working on developing a piece of code which executes within and accesses data from a commercial radiation planning software (Eclipse). 
I'm attempting to have this application.exe also update some model parameters within a SolidWorks model.

Here's the problem:
When attempting to open the SolidWorks application (SldWorks swApp = new SldWorks(); ) i get an error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CSLID {xxx-xxx-xxx} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

I have also attempted the methods described here:

https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/getting-started/stand-alone/
After attempting these methods, I receive again the same error.

I understand that this means that the application is attempting to access something in the registry that isn't there, but it isn't clear what I should do to remedy this.

I am running Solidworks 2018 in Windows 7, using Visual Studio Community 2017 as my editor.  The piece of code works on its own, and I believe I have all of the relevant Solidworks .dll's referenced properly in my model. Interestingly, if i run the same code as a .dll from within Visual Studio, Solidworks will actually open. This is done using the "SldWorks swApp = new SldWorks();" methodology (which is a part of the Solidworks API methods)

I have no build errors in my solution.  I apologize if there is anything confusing in this, as I am new to C# and these APIs. I will do my best to clarify any questions.

I have attempted the methods here:
[C#: DLL is registered but COM error 80040154 still appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618287/c-dll-is-registered-but-com-error-80040154-still-appear) to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: DLL is registered but COM error 80040154 still appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618287/c-dll-is-registered-but-com-error-80040154-still-appear)

Comment: See comments on the bottom of my post.

Comment: Do you have Embed Interop Types set to false for the Solidworks dlls?

Comment: I created default C# console application, included reference c:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll
and SldWorks app = new SldWorks(); works fine.
Try to make your application as 64 bit since SolidWorks 2018 is 64 bit app. 
What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: @ehcanadian I do.

Comment: @VladyslavLitunovsky Right. I can make a console application, and this will open SW etc, but the problem is that when this line is executed from my console application from within Eclipse, everything fails.

Comment: @VladyslavLitunovsky I am using 4.6.1

Comment: Please check that you can find SolidWorks in registry when you run it from Eclipse.
RegistryKey lm = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey sw = lm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\SldWorks.Application");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", new[] { sw, sw.GetValue("") }));
Console.WriteLine(sw.OpenSubKey("CLSID").GetValue(""));

Comment: @VladyslavLitunovsky I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object at the sw.GetValue(""); command.

Comment: It looks you either don't have access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE from Eclipse or you restricted to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node as 32bit process.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering swpublished dll

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\api\redist\SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished.dll" /codebase

You can also check if 32/64 bit registry has anything to do with your issue. Create a test project that will call new SldWorks() and run it first as 32bit then as 64bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response Vlad, while I don't use swpublished, I have done exactly this with the sldworks.dll file. My understanding is that the eclipse files must be run as 64, so I've been doing that. I built a teat project for just Solidworks and this works just fine.

Comment: My understanding is even though you do not use swpublished directly it still contains necessary COM registrations.